# Non tail-recursive anonymous functions in Clojure

Tags: recursion, lambda, clojure

How do I create a recursive anonymous function in Clojure which is not tail recursive?

The following clearly doesn't work, as `recur` is only for tail recursive functions.  I'm also reluctant to drag in a y-combinator..

```
((fn [n] (if (= 1 n) 1 (* n (recur (dec n))))) 5)
```

Comment: "Just give it a name"? They call me Mr. Anonymous... :P~

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Functions can be given a name to refer to themselves by specifying it between `fn` and the arglist:

```
user> ((fn ! [n] (if (= 1 n) 1 (* n (! (dec n))))) 5)
120
```

Comment: yay for naming anonymous functions! +1

Comment: Calling it `!` seems to run counter to convention, since it's not mutating anything.

Comment: The function he's defined is the factorial function. I could have called it `fact`, but mathematicians call it !, and we're working in a language that allows us to call it the same. Seems silly to write something longer when everyone knows that 5! is 120.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that keeps it anonymous, mostly:

```
(((fn [!] (fn [n] (if (= 1 n) 1 (* n ((! !) (dec n)))))) 
  (fn [!] (fn [n] (if (= 1 n) 1 (* n ((! !) (dec n))))))) 
 5)
```

It's not quite the Y combinator, but it does contain the same bit of self-application that allows Y to do its thing. By having a copy of the entire function in scope as `!` whenever you need it, you can always make another copy.

Comment: You can remove some of the duplication there with this:
(((fn [!] (fn [n] ((! !) n))) (fn [!] (fn [n] (if (= 1 n) 1 (* n ((! !) (dec n))))))) 5)

This clearly isn't the way to do it (given that Clojure can name the fns, but I still like it. :)