# define recursive function in let form

Tags: clojure

Is it possible in Clojure to define a recursive function inside a `let` form or should a `letfn` be used instead? For instance, can I do the below using `let`?

```
(defn blowStackExample []
  (letfn [(blowStack []
            (blowStack))]
    (blowStackExample)))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non tail-recursive anonymous functions in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626641/non-tail-recursive-anonymous-functions-in-clojure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you can do it is by naming the anonymous function inside the `fn` form:

```
(defn blow-up-stack-example []
  (let [blow-up-stack (fn a [] (a))]
    (blow-up-stack)))
    
(blow-up-stack-example)
```